# Reliablility of Statement.getGeneratedKeys()

Tags: java, jdbc

I found that `Statement.getGeneratedKeys()` can be used for retrieving the ids of the inserted rows. But I wanted to know is it reliable, if we have multiple JDBC connections performing insert operation simultaneously.

Comment: are you sharing the `Statement` across multiple connections?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you expect this particular method to be unreliable? Why would it be any other than `executeStatement()`?

Comment: I don't know how the method is implemented. After Insert operation to get the Auto Incremented ID it might require to look up the DataBase again, I suspected if some rows are added by other thread the result would get affected. But in case of executeStatement() it can easily keep track of successful execution.

Answer (score 1):

From [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys()) of `getGeneratedKeys()`

> Retrieves any auto-generated keys created as a result of executing this Statement object.

When you create a Statement from a Connection Object, the generated keys are belongs to that particular statement. And they return the specific id's inserted. So you'll safely get those.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine without problem until and unless you are using JDBC properly.I am using getGeneratedKeys() since long time and didn't came across any issue till now.